# Insert PDF generated by LaTeX inside another PDF

Tags: pdf

I'm not sure this is the right place to ask that, so if it is not, sorry.

**Context:** My maths teacher writes her lessons with LaTeX. I take notes using LaTeX too, and I'd like to insert my notes into her lessons. However, she does not want to share the source code, I only have the PDF. Currently, I have to look at two PDFs, it is quite inconvenient.

So I'm trying to insert the PDF generated by LaTeX inside another PDF.

For example, there's theorem 1 and theorem 2 on the first page of her lesson. I'd like to insert proof 1 and proof 2, from my notes, into that lesson.

There's probably a way to do it manually, but I want to repeat this process quite a few times. So I'm wondering if there is a way to automate that?

Thanks

Comment: The easiest is to use the pdfpages package, but there are also several command line tools to merge pdfs

Comment: Could you please give an example? @daleif

Comment: You can insert pages using `pdfpages` from the lesson PDF into your notes. You can't do it the other way (with LaTeX). You also can't insert proofs onto the page the theorems are on. (Unless there's space and you really want to mess around with overlays or something.) But you could put say page 1 of the lesson, then some pages of notes, then page 2 and so on.

Comment: @cfr That's what I was afraid of, but that's already better than nothing. Thanks